# PostgreSQL foreign key with condition

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have got 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(30),
    salary money
); 
CREATE TABLE Doctor(
    employee_id integer,
    speciality varchar(30),
    cabinet integer,
    foreign key (employee_id) references Employee
);
```

Now I need to create table DoctorsAssistant, which is very similar to Doctor's table, but I faced the problem of checking some Employee wouldn't be Doctor and Doctor's Assistant at the same time, as both of them will have Employee id as foreign key. How can I manage it?

Comment: imho your design is wrong. You should have a table `employee` and another one `empolyee_role` where you can manage different types of employees. Then create a relationship 1,2 or 1,n (if necessary)

Comment: I would suggest you have a design more like so: `role` table which has values like `(1, 'Podiatrist'), (2, 'Doctor's Assistant')`, a `employee_type` table with `(1, 'Assistant'), (2, 'Doctor')`, then `employee` table with a structure of `id ..., name ..., employee_type (fk ref'ing employee_type table), role (fk ref'ing role table)`.

Comment: If you choose to use the design suggested by `404` you will be able to represent someone who is a doctor (by his title) but just today is working as assistant to someone else, who is also an assistant (by her title) but today is acting as a doctor for this particular patient.